# How can /resources/js/common.js file read value from .env file?

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

In my laravel 8 vuejs 2.6 I have a js file /resources/js/common.js with OAuth client ID:

```
import Vue from "vue";
import axios from "axios";
import $ from "jquery";
import { initFbsdk } from "./fb.js";
import { LoaderPlugin } from "vue-google-login";
import "../../public/frontassets/js/mmenu.min.js";

Vue.use(LoaderPlugin, {
    client_id:
        "NNNNNNN-NNNN.apps.googleusercontent.com"
});
```

As this OAuth client ID must be different on my local OS and DEV/LIVE server I wonder if there is a way
to read this from laravel's .env file, which is different on any OS?

This /resources/js/common.js is not included in webpack.mix.js file.

Thanks!

Comment: You can either pass the value of `client_id` to JavaScript when returning the page from the server via PHP or you create an API endpoint which returns the .env file and/or a value of it by key. While the latter is the cleaner way, it's also the less secure one since you might expose secret values to the public.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using Laravel, I'll assume you build your Javascript using Mix.

Mix supports reading vales from the `.env`, as long as you prefix them with `MIX_`.

For more Information, see the Laravel documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/mix#environment-variables

If you don't want to prefix your variables with `MIX_` there is a webpack plugin which allows you to read the full `.env` file:
https://github.com/mrsteele/dotenv-webpack

There is also a section on how to include custom webpack configs in the documentation:
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/mix#custom-webpack-configuration